# what can I do to get a chargeback from an online retailer purchased on my credit card

Tags: credit-card, chargeback, online-retailer

I bought shoes on the internet. The refund policy was clear that you could return the shoes for any reason but I the buyer would have to pay shipping. The shoes didn't fit. Part of the store policy is that the customer is required to contact them to arrange the return, an RMA. The problem is that the company will not respond to any of my correspondence with them. After more than a week without any response, I wrote the bank to put the charge in contention. The bank sent a long form to fill out, which I did and submitted to the bank online. Now the bank wrote to say that they "don't see a billing error". I never said there was a billing error! This is chase bank in the U.S.

This seems totally unreasonable to me. I've had problems like this in the past and the bank refunds the money to me.

What can I do to get the bank to give me a refund from what appears to be an unscrupuolus company?

Comment: Call up Chase, and tell them they made a mistake in thinking it's billing error.

Comment: Did you claim it was a billing error in the paperwork? Tell them the product was not as advertised (not the size you ordered).  Also did these shoes take weeks to arrive and come from China?

Comment: I agree with @RonJohn that you should try calling your CC directly. In the past when I've done chargebacks over the phone they ask questions and then they take care of it. I assume they fill out whatever forms are required for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't paid your bill yet, your money doesn't exactly need to be "refunded", you're looking for your account to be credited. Since you've filed for a chargeback, you shouldn't have to pay while the chargeback is being disputed. If you disagree with Chase's handling, you can file a complaint with the card network (since it's Chase, that is probably VISA, but they also have some Mastercard).